# Pgfplots: trim / clip surface plot with curve

Tags: pgfplots

Assume I have a surface plot like the one below, for which I would like to trim or clip the area beyond the red curve (i.e., the area beyond the red curve should show no color). Can this be somehow achieved by `pgfplots`? Many thanks in advance!

If there is no reasonable way of doing so, I'd be very happy with some workaround ...

[image: surface plot]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1, colormap name=viridis, view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp] {exp(-x^2-y^2)};
    \addplot3 [smooth, thick, red] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.75,0.75,0) (1,0,0)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:1, colormap name=viridis, view={0}{90}]
    \clip (0,0) -- (0,1) -- plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.75,0.75,0) (1,0,0)} -- cycle;
    \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp] {exp(-x^2-y^2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with upper right corner clipped]

-or with red curve:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:1, colormap name=viridis, view={0}{90}]
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) -- (0,1) -- plot[smooth] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.75,0.75,0) (1,0,0)} -- cycle;
\addplot3 [surf, shader=interp] {exp(-x^2-y^2)};
\end{scope}
\addplot3 [smooth, thick, red] coordinates {(0,1,0) (0.75,0.75,0) (1,0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Same graph with red curve]

Comment: Awesome! I have imagined it to be much more complicated, as the three-dimensional surface doesn't really intersect the curve.